# How to send a POST message from MQL4 to NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, mql4

**`webrequest.mq4`**

```
#property copyright "Copyright 2013, apla"
#property link      "-"

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| expert start function                                            |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int start()
{
//----    
// WebRequest
   string cookie = NULL;
   string headers = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   int res;

   string url = "localhost:8080";                              // url = localhost:8080
   char post[], result[];
   string signal = "account=" + AccountNumber() + "&balance=" + AccountBalance() + "&equity=" + AccountEquity(); 
   StringToCharArray( signal, post );
   Print( signal );
   int timeout = 5000;                                   // 5 sec
   res = WebRequest( "POST",
                     url,
                     cookie,
                     NULL,
                     timeout,
                     post,
                     ArraySize( post ),
                     result,
                     headers
                     );

   Print( "Status code: " , res, ", error: ", GetLastError() );
//----
   return(0);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to send a file from MetaTrader Terminal 4 `webrequest.mq4` to a Node this Site section that can be given up, however.

MT4 >> Nodejs

??? POST[] ??? (JavaScript nodes)
account, balance, equity

how to convert file.php to nodejs

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "account ".$_POST['account']."\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "balance ".$_POST['balance']."\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "equity ".$_POST['equity']."\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

For which I do not know how to get the POST.

`writeFile.js`

```
var http = require('http'); var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile("file.txt",??? POST[] ???, function(err,data) {
     if (err) throw err; 
     console.log('The file was saved!');

     http.createServer(function(req, res) {
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
          res.end('OK'); 
}).listen(8080); 
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8080/'); });
```

Comment: Please clean up the format of the question.

Comment: ok i clean up format

Answer (score 1):

kindly be attentive to details:

### <kbd>Step 0 :</kbd>
`MQL4` part
should follow the recent *New-*`MQL4.56789`<sup>copy/paste code fails</sup>

As a first sign of this, <kbd>`MetaTrader Terminal 4`</kbd> code-base statically present on web does not reflect creeping syntax changes of `MQL4` language. Recently `MQL4` has moved closer to `MQL5` ( reasoning for which is outside of this post, if interested, check other posts about *New-*`MQL4.56789` ).

```
int start(){...}             // cannot be used anymore,
                             //           neither for EXPERT_ADVISOR
                             //           nor     for SCRIPT
```

Recent `#property strict` compilation mode imposes use of:

```
 void OnTick(){         ...} // for EXPERT_ADVISOR   type of MQL4-code
 void OnStart(){        ...} // for SCRIPT           type of MQL4-code
 int  OnCalculate(...){ ...} // for CUSTOM_INDICATOR type of MQL4-code,
                             // while,
                             //     CUSTOM_INDICATOR has explicitly
                             //     FORBIDDEN any attempt
                             //     call to a WebRequest( ... ) et al
```

This said, your **`MQL4`**-part of the code shall be modified in it's principal structure so as to reflect these facts.

For any further tasks, related to **`MQL4`**, rather use `localhost` installed **`Help`**-service from the **`IDE`**, searching for *"help"* on web will most of all become a misleading source for un-edited copy/paste attempts due to above presented reasons.

---

### <kbd>Step 1 :</kbd>
`POST` http-syntax construction
ought be conformant to `RFC 7231`, `Section 4.3.3`

as a minimum, your constructed text, being stored into a **`string signal`** ought look something like this:

```
User-Agent: aplaHTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 54

account=123456789&balance=1234567.89&equity=1234567.89
```

---

### <kbd>Step 2 :</kbd>
Node.js part
parse received parameters for whatever further post-processing

Similarly, the `node.js` part shall decipher the parameters delivered inside **`POST`**-url-encoded http-message.

And the job is done.

---

Welcome to the **Wild Worlds of `MQL4`**